# How would one translate 綺麗 (きれい) in this context?

Tags: translation, terminology

I am currently translating some content regarding Aikido, and have been getting stuck on how to translate 綺麗 (きれい) in the following context:

> しっかりとした、綺麗な半身を作ることを心がけて下さい。

It's discussing a bodily position where the body is standing nearly profile (sideways) to an opponent or partner. I don't believe that describing the position as "beautiful", "neat", or "tidy" would express it in the context here. I'm tempted towards "clear", or even with some interpretive license, "composed".

Comment: I've heard reference in martial arts to having a "**clean** stance", presumably that would work in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your choice of "clear" is fair. This 綺麗 means "well-formed; matching the prescriptive form (which gives a stylish impression)". You can see some cognitive relation with "beautiful" or "tidy" sense as well. "Clean" that @EiríkrÚtlendi suggested is equally good.

> 綺麗なコード *clean (source) code*
>   綺麗な六角形 *perfect hexagon*
>   綺麗なイギリス英語 *clear British accent*

Comment: Thank you, in the end I accepted "clear", resulting in:

"Please try to take a sturdy and clear hanmi."

"Hanmi" being an established term in our working glossary, referring to a profiled position, so that bit remained in romaji.